# Invalid character error in IE 10 when parsing web service response

Tags: jquery

I am calling a c# webservice from my javascript code in aspx page to get server side data. Service returns data in JSON format. When I parse the data in client side I am getting invalid character error in IE10. 
But surprisingly same code works perfectly fine in IE9. Also there is no error at service end.
Below is the code snippet.

```
var data = {};
data.qualificationid = SOME-ID;

$.ajax({
method: 'GET',
url: "WebServices/MyService.asmx/GetHistoryData",
data: data,
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
cache: false,
success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    var res = JSON.parse(data.text);
    //** this data.text is always undefined **
      ...
    }
```

});

Comment: Which line is raising the error?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when using jQuery's `$.parseJSON()` (instead of `JSON.parse()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, though weird behaviour in IE10.
Tried JSON.Parse as well $.parseJSON() but was not working in ie10. As problem was more with the response extraction (data.text) in above sample.

But it works like a charm when I use as below in stead of data.text.

```
$(data).find('string').text()
```